# Upload video in base64 - Adding a progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I tried to upload a video in an input file,  then i convert in base64..it's possible to add a progress bar instead to *readAsDataURL* ?

The code is similar to this example:
http://codepen.io/kilianso/pen/MKjYPx

```
<div>  
  <input type="file" accept="video/*" id="VidExp" name="VidExp"> 
  <video preload="none" autoplay="autoplay" id="upload_vid" class="cstepVid" src="" alt=""></video>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.upload_vid[src=""]').hide();
  $('.upload_vid:not([src=""])').show();
});

function readURLVid(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#upload_vid').attr('src', e.target.result);
      $('#preview_vid').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#VidExp").change(function() {
  readURLVid(this);
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to upload a base64 encoded binary file? Why not just use `FormData`

Comment: Because in base64 I can upload  the file without using an uploader.php or ajax upload

Comment: Why would you want to do that though? It's the root of the speed problem. Just upload it as binary

Comment: I have a restriction in client side, i use ajax to send data() and the base64 is converted in server side for sending to cdn. Then, it's possible upload the video in cache or something?